# elements order in the inline css made by CGI scripting is not as the same as their order in the created HTML file

Tags: perl, cgi, perl-module

I am working on a beginner `CGI` scripting by using `CGI.pm` for school project.
I need to get some data from user and implement them into `HTML` as an inline css.

pop is a pop menu to decide the unit for width of the `DIV`.

```
if ( $cgi->param('width') ) {
print
$cgi->div(
{
    -style=>'width:'.$cgi->param('width').$cgi->param('pop').';'.'align:'=>$cgi->param('justification').';',
},
$cgi->p($cgi->param('area')),
);
}
```

my HTML source is weird. why they are not in the order?

```
<div right;width:50% style="align:"><p>here is my text</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling warnings would have told you:

```
Odd number of elements in anonymous hash
```

because you have `... => ... => ...` there; I suspect the second one was meant to be `.`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
my $cgi = CGI->new("width=50;pop=%25;justification=right");
if ( $cgi->param('width') ) {
    print
$cgi->div(
{
    -style=>'width:'.$cgi->param('width').$cgi->param('pop').';'.'align:'.$cgi->param('justification').';',
},
$cgi->p($cgi->param('area')),
);
}
```

output:

```
<div style="width:50%;align:right;"><p /></div>
```